# Google Drive can't get change resource when file is deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API to manage a user's files. Currently, I start a watch channel to listen for any changes made to the user's files, and they are sent to a webhook I have setup. The update/new file changes work fine, but when a file is deleted, I have this issue:

```
19:59:40 work.1    | D, [2016-11-07T19:59:40.751115 #8526] DEBUG -- : [httplog] Response:
19:59:40 work.1    | {
19:59:40 work.1    |  "error": {
19:59:40 work.1    |   "errors": [
19:59:40 work.1    |    {
19:59:40 work.1    |     "domain": "global",
19:59:40 work.1    |     "reason": "notFound",
19:59:40 work.1    |     "message": "Change not found: 1579",
19:59:40 work.1    |     "locationType": "other",
19:59:40 work.1    |     "location": "change"
19:59:40 work.1    |    }
19:59:40 work.1    |   ],
19:59:40 work.1    |   "code": 404,
19:59:40 work.1    |   "message": "Change not found: 1579"
19:59:40 work.1    |  }
19:59:40 work.1    | }
```

Problem is, this is the final change resource I get on the webhook. The output of my request listener shows this below:

[image]

Why is this happening? Note that the last three googledrive/webhook requests all have the same id. Could that be the problem?

I've been coming back to this in and out of a month or two now, so any new ideas, or even a rubber duck to talk to, would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346106/404-change-not-found-message-of-push-notification-api-and-get-changes-api

Comment: It's close, but the problem is I make no other changes to the file. I simple right click it, and hit delete. Then I get these three webhooks, all of the same change resource ID, but all of which are invalid